# Error when adding a member to a marketplace project

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I am migrating an application to the new Google Marketplace.
To do so I have created a project in the Google API Console.

To test the installation flow, I need to share the project with a test account. I have added this account as a member of the project ("Permissions" tab of the project).
My test account has been sent an invitation to join the project.

The problem is when he accepts the invitation, he gets an error pop up (title : server error, content: undefined)

When I track the call with firebug, I can see that I have a call that fails

```
https://cloud.google.com/console/m/teams/showinvitation?pid=xxx&token=xxx&authuser=0
```

the response of this call is

```
{"code":5,"details":"ACCOUNT_DISABLED: Account disabled","status":400,"message":"5"}
```

Does someone know what this means ? Is my test email a disabled account ? Is my project a disabled account ?

Lou

Comment: This is more likely a bug with the Google API Console or something weird going on with your test account. Is the test account in good standing? What do you see when you go to plus.google.com?

Comment: I have enabled the "Google App Engine Admin Console" in the services activated in my test account. Now, I get another error, when my user on my test account clicks on the sharing link, he gets a pop up "Welcome, my_test_account!Join this project!". If he clicks on accept, he gets "Error. You have no more apps available to accept this invitation."  Do you know what this means ?

Comment: Can you try adding them on the old console? And also have them try accessing it via the same console? https://code.google.com/apis/console/?noredirect

Comment: I cannot add them in the old console : I can only open the projects which are already shared with me. I have also tried to access directly  to the project with my test account by opening "https://cloud.google.com/console/project/apps~project_id" logged in with me test account but I get the following message "Error
The project you requested is unavailable."

Comment: When I try to share with only the read right, when the test account tries to accept the invitation I get the following error "Error
The specified invitation was not found."